# Proving $x_ky_k\to ab $

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Prove that  the sequence $x_ky_k\to ab $ if $x_k\to a$ and $y_k\to b$.

I wanted to try and do this with the epsilon definition but i am having a few technical issues.

Proof:

$$ |x_ky_k - ab| = |x_k - a||y_k| + |a||y_k - b|$$

Now i tried to use the idea of bounding that coukd be done in continuity arguments, specifically i tried to bound $y_k $:

$$|y_k - b| < \frac{\epsilon}{2} \implies -\frac{\epsilon}{2} + b \leq y_k \leq \frac{\epsilon}{2} + b$$

Now i tried to argue that we know each sequence converges up to a specific value K, therefore:

$$ |x_k - K_1||\frac{\epsilon}{2}+b| + |a||y_k - K_2|$$

Using those i obtain :

$$K_1 = \frac{\epsilon}{2}\frac{2}{\epsilon +2b} - x_k =\frac{\epsilon}{\epsilon +2b} - x_k$$
$$ K_2 =\frac{\epsilon}{2}\frac{1}{|a|} - y_k $$

Being the two values of K that each sequence converges to, then selecting the maximum of those two values would imply convergence of the product.

In trying to relate it to how the epsilon argument works with continutiy i proba ly made some mistakes. For one , i don't think i can bound my sequence in that fashion and from there perhaps using that bound ruined the argument. But if i don't attempt something and get feedback i won't know right?

Comment: I think this needs clarification.  What are ${x_k},{y_k},a,b$?  What assumptions are you starting from?

Comment: Are you possibly asking:  "Given that $\{x_k\}\rightarrow a$ and $\{y_k\}\rightarrow b$ show that $\{x_ky_k\}\rightarrow ab$"?  Where, let's say, everything is a real number?

Comment: I changed the start of the problem slightly, so let me know if I changed it incorrectly.

Comment: You changed it correctly. I am asking about the convergence of the product of sequences

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first line should have a "$\leq$" instead of "$=$", since you are using the triangle inequality:
$$
|x_ky_k-ab|=|x_ky_k-ay_k+ay_k-ab|\leq|x_k-a||y_k|+|a||y_k-b|.
$$
Your next idea is totally fine, but you are making things more complicated than they are :) First, fix $\epsilon>0$. Since $(x_k)$ converges to $a$ and since $(y_k)$ converges to $b$, we know three things:

(1) Every convergent sequence is bounded, so in particular, there exists some constant $C>0$ such that $|y_k|\leq C$ for all $k$.

(2) There is some startindex $K'\in\mathbb N$ such that $|y_k-b|\leq\frac{\epsilon}{2|a|}$ for each $k\geq K'$.

(3) Similar to (2): There is some startindex $K''\in\mathbb N$ such that $|x_k-a|\leq\frac{\epsilon}{2C}$ for each $k\geq K''$.

Now put everything together. If we define $K:=\max\{K',K''\}$, then (2) and (3) are satisfied for all $k\geq K$. Using these in the very first inequality gives
$$
|x_ky_k-ab|\leq|x_k-a||y_k|+|a||y_k-b|\leq\frac{\epsilon}{2C}\cdot C+|a|\cdot\frac{\epsilon}{2|a|}=\epsilon
$$
for all $k\geq K$, and this shows that $(x_ky_k)$ converges to $ab$.

Note that in your solution, $K_1=a$ and $K_2=b$, since $(x_k)$ converges to $a$ and $(y_k)$ converges to $b$.
Also note that the above proof inplicitly requires $|a|\neq0$. But if $|a|=0$, then the second term of the triangle inequality disappears, and then the proof works even if $(y_k)$ is only bounded (and not necessarily convergent). Think about it ;)

Comment: Awesome. Thanks alot. I always tend to forget that if a sequence converges that means it is bounded.  For 3) did you mean $x_k $ instead of $y_k$?

Comment: Yes, sry, thank you!